# Derivative of a symplectic form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $\gamma \in C^\infty(I,M)$ a path in $M$. For $X,Y \in \Gamma_\gamma(TM)$ I would like to compute the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dt}\omega(X(t),Y(t)).$$
My intuition somehow tells me that this is equal to
$$\omega(\dot{X}(t),Y(t)) + \omega(X(t),\dot{Y}(t)),$$
but working in local coordinates this does not look right. I think that one has to interpret the dot as a covariant derivative. Thus I tried to use an $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure $J$ to derive
$$\frac{d}{dt}\omega(X(t),Y(t)) = -\frac{d}{dt}\omega(JJX(t),Y(t)) = -\omega(J\nabla_t JX,Y(t)) + \omega(X(t),\nabla_t Y).$$
**But then I am stucked.**

Comment: Why is $\nabla$ a symplectic connection?  You should get a term $(\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\omega)(X,Y)$ in Leibniz rule.

Comment: @user10354138 I used the formula $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle V,W \rangle = \langle \nabla_tV,W \rangle + \langle V,\nabla_t W \rangle$$ for a Riemannian metric and the assumption that $\omega(J\cdot,\cdot)$ is a Riemannian metric. Ah but if I use a symplectic connection (which always exists) the above formula is correct right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you write down implicitly requires a connection (since it involves derivatives of vector fields), so doesn't mean anything on an arbitrary symplectic manifold until you choose a connection. Unlike Riemannian manifolds, there is no canonical choice of connection on a symplectic manifold, unless it is endowed with some extra structure.

Having chosen a connection $\nabla$, the statement you give,
$$
\nabla_V(\omega(X,Y))=\omega(\nabla_VX,Y)+\omega(X,\nabla_VY)\iff \nabla\omega=0
$$
may or may not hold. When it does, we say $\nabla$ is *compatible with* $\omega$. Such connections always exist, but they are not unique.

A symplectic connection on $(M,\omega)$ is a torsion free connection compatible with $\omega$. These always exist as well, but are again not unique.

Your choice of connection seems to assume that $(M,\omega)$ has additional structure. If we instead have a Kähler manifold $(M,\omega,g,J)$, there is a canonical connection in the form of the Levy-Civita connection $\nabla_g$ associated with $g$. The compatibility conditions on the Kähler structure imply that $\nabla_g$ is compatible with $\omega$. Not every symplectc manifold admits a Kähler structure.

Comment: My question originates in computing the Hessian of the Rabinowitz functional. I asked this question a few times on MathOverflow, but the question was always ignored. Maybe you could give it a try, as it is similar to this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366534/derivative-of-a-pullback-by-a-2-parameter-family. In the end, the choice of symplectic connection does not matter.